# Imported Patch colors not working correctly in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I've been trying to get my turtles to 'bounce' off a wall using Netlogo.

I've imported a png file that has the colors of the different surfaces (walls, interface, liquid, heater eventually there will be a few more). I used MSPaint and the colormap from [netlogo color chart](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#colors) to create my shapes (a purple square, with brown on the side borders, red border on the bottom and blue border on the top)

What I'm trying to do is have the turtles start on the liquid patches and move in straight lines until they bump into a surface (different colored wall). If they bump into a wall, they should 'bounce' off in a random direction, if they hit the heater, their temperature should go increase and they should also bounce off of the heater surface. If they bump into the interface and their temperature is above 100, they should move through the interface and then move around above the interface (basically teleport up a few pixels).

The issue I'm having is that the turtles move around and they appear to be bouncing off the walls just fine, but they seem to be oblivious to the colors of the heater and the interface. I'm sure I'm missing something basic or obvious, but I've been struggling for three days on this same quirk. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have right now:
(in this code I have it set to just 'teleport' through the interface regardless of the temperature of the water)

```
 globals[ liquid-color  heater-color  wall-color  reflection-color  air-color  interface-color
          liquid        heater        wall        reflection        air        interface]

    breed [h2o water]
to setup
  clear-turtles
  reset-ticks
  clear-all-plots

  import-pcolors "boilermap.png"

  set liquid-color 115
  set heater-color 19
  set wall-color 35
  set interface-color 105

  setup-patches
  create-molecules
end


to setup-patches
  set heater patches with [pcolor = heater-color]
  set heater-color 19
  ask heater [set pcolor 19]

  set interface  patches with [pcolor = interface-color]
  set interface-color 105
  ask interface [set pcolor 105]

  set liquid patches with [pcolor = liquid-color]
  set liquid-color 115
  ask liquid [set pcolor 115]

  set wall patches with [pcolor = wall-color]
  set wall-color 35
  ask wall [set pcolor 35]

end


to create-molecules

  create-h2o (totalmoles * h20number / 100)[
    set shape "circle"
    set color black
    set size 2
    set temperature 20
    setxy random xcor random ycor
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = liquid-color]
  ]

to go
  ask h2o [
    (ifelse
      pcolor = liquid-color[fd 1 ];ifblock
      pcolor = heater-color [set temperature temperature + 5]
      pcolor = interface-color [set ycor ycor + 100] ;just trying to get them to jump here, regardless of their temperature
     ;elseblock 
    [ bk 1
      rt random 180]
    )]

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diesel, you have a great start on this!    I put some code below that answers your questions.

By the way, the title on your question doesn't really match what your actual problem was: imported patch colors not working correctly

I suspect the reason your code ignores the heater and interface is that they imported as pcolors that don't match the ones you expected.   I added a verify-colors command that checks to see if the imported colors are correct.  I also added an option to generate a new boiler image you can work with in case importing still causes more problems.

Also, I notice you are adding 100 to ycor when your molecule hits the interface.  It's possible this moves the molecule entirely up out of view, which could be confusing, as the default view is only 32 units high.  I changed the 100 to 5 to keep the molecule in view.

I cleaned up a few more things and confirmed the model ran successfully.   The handling of correct bouncing off walls and off the heater was not addressed -- that's your job!

Here's the things I tweaked in your code:
;; 
;; added h2o-own section so molecules each have a temperature
;; added a user-choice of whether to import the boilermap.png or create a new one here
;;    if importing, verify the colors exactly match the valid colors
;;    added "make-drawing" and "verify-colors" sections at the end
;; moved reset-ticks to the end of setup, its usual location
;; added ticks to the end of the go section !!
;; added set-aircolor grey  ( it wasn't defined )
;; cleaned out unneeded commands from the setup-patches section.  You already have the
pcolors imported, so you don't need to set them again.

;; added "set label temperature" to the create-molecules section as well as to the place
;;   where temperature is increased at the heater, so each molecule shows its current temperature

I tested it with interface variables h2o-number =100 and total-moles either 1 or 5 and speed set to very slow.  It works!

```
globals[ liquid-color  heater-color  wall-color  reflection-color  air-color  interface-color
          liquid        heater        wall        reflection        air        interface]

    breed [h2o water]

h2o-own [
  temperature 
]

to setup
  clear-turtles

  clear-all-plots

  set liquid-color 115
  set heater-color 19
  set wall-color 35
  set interface-color 105
  set air-color grey

  if-else user-yes-or-no? "import boilermap.png?"
  [ 
    import-pcolors "boilermap.png"
    verify-colors  ;;     check the command section for counts of pcolors
  ]
  [
    make-drawing  ;; just make a new image of a boiler
  ]

   setup-patches
   create-molecules
   reset-ticks  ;;  usually, do this as the last step in setup
end


to setup-patches
  set heater patches with [pcolor = heater-color]
  set interface  patches with [pcolor = interface-color]
  set liquid patches with [pcolor = liquid-color]
  set wall patches with [pcolor = wall-color]
end


to create-molecules
  no-display
  create-h2o (totalmoles * h20number / 100)[
    set shape "circle"
    set color black
    set size 2
    set temperature 20
    setxy random xcor random ycor
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = liquid-color]
    set label temperature
  ]
  display
end

to go 
  ask h2o [
    (ifelse
      pcolor = liquid-color[fd 1 ] 
      pcolor = heater-color [ set temperature temperature + 5  set label temperature  set heading 0 forward 1]
      pcolor = interface-color [set ycor ycor + 5  forward 1  ]  
      pcolor = wall-color and pxcor < 0 [set heading 135 forward 1]
      pcolor = wall-color and pxcor > 0 [set heading 220 forward 1]
    [ bk 1
      rt random 180]
    )]
tick   ; DONT FORGET THIS !!
end

;; ========================== new utility functions ===

to make-drawing
   no-display           
   ask patches with [ pycor > 1] [ set pcolor air-color]
   ask patches with [ pycor < 1] [set pcolor liquid-color]
   ask patches with [ abs pycor <= 1]   [ set pcolor interface-color]
   ask patches with [ pycor < (min-pycor + 4)] [ set pcolor heater-color]
   ask patches with [ pxcor > (max-pxcor - 2)] [ set pcolor wall-color]
   ask patches with [ pxcor < (min-pxcor + 2)] [ set pcolor wall-color]
   ask patches with [ pycor > (max-pycor - 2)] [ set pcolor wall-color]
   ask patches with [ pycor < (min-pycor + 2)] [ set pcolor wall-color]
   display
end

to verify-colors   ;; see what we imported
  let good-colors (list 
    liquid-color  
    heater-color  
    wall-color  
    interface-color  
    air-color )
  let good-count count patches with [member? pcolor good-colors]
  let bad-count count patches - good-count
  type "good patch count " type good-count type ", bad patch count: " print bad-count
  if bad-count > 0 [ if "no" = user-yes-or-no? " bad patch colors, should I continue?" [stop] ]
end
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much! Turns out almost none of my colors are being imported correctly. I think i'll take the approach you have here of drawing in the shape rather than importing an image. Fortunately my geometry will be fairly basic for this model.